# Silverlight: How to create a page dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

**Problem:** I store the page name I want opened in Silverlight in a database. When I startup the application I want to set the page to this string

so rather than this:

```
this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
```

I want something like this

```
string pageName = getValueFromDatabase()
if (!PageExists(pageName))
   throw error
else
   this.RootVisual = SomeWizzyMethodToCreatePage(pageName)
```

I guess I will need to use reflection here to find all of the pages (PageExists), and then somehow create a new instance (SomeWizzyMethodToCreatePage).

Comment: When you say you store the page you want to open in a database do you actually mean you store the __name__ of the page you want to open?

Comment: yes, the name. Have updated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you mean the you aquire from the DB the **name** of the page that you want to determine the name of the page to display.

I'll take the simplest example where all the pages are in a single application assembly and a single known namespace.  It can be as simple as this:-

```
Type pageType = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("SilverlightApplication1." + pageName);
RootVisual = (UIElement)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
```

Perhaps a more flexibable approach would be to store in the database an `AssemblyQualifiedName`.  That way the page can be in a different assembly and/or namespace, it need only be present in the XAP (I'm not sure whether it can be in a cached assembly library zip).  If the page name is an `AssemblyQualifiedName` then the code becomes:-

```
Type pageType = Type.GetType(pageName);
RootVisual = (UIElement)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, Anthony! +1 from me. Cheers.

Comment: Works great... just had to add my Views Namespace .GetType("SilverlightApplication1.Views." + pageName);