# Silverlight control in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

i have two silverlight user controls name region.xaml and session.xaml and i want to place them in region.aspx and session.aspx respectively. The problem is that in both the aspx pages i am getting the region.xaml control how to fix it hta in the session.aspx session.xaml control will be displayed.

Comment: Give version numbers, show small sample of your failing page.

Comment: i dont understand what u need i have a silverlight project containing 2 controls i.e. xaml files and i want to display them in seperate pages in my aspx web site project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution:

first we need to set the properties in

and then need to ammed the App.xaml file of silverlight application as shown below:

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        string ControlID = "ControlID";
        if (e.InitParams.ContainsKey(ControlID))
        {
            switch (e.InitParams[ControlID])
            {
                case "RegionControl":
                    this.RootVisual = new RegionControl();
                    break;

                case "SessionControl":
                    this.RootVisual = new SessionControl();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: See my answer to a similar requirement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338016/silverlight-how-to-create-a-page-dynamically/2338131#2338131