# How do I add a UserControl dynamically when all I have is the name of the control in a string format? Silverlight, C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, dynamic, user-controls

I'm working on calling different user controls, and the only data that I've been given is a string in which to call the user control that I have created. When I know the name, I can hard code and add that control in the code behind and add it dynamically that way, but when the name of the control is being passed to me via a string, I'm having trouble passing that to my usercontrol object and having it not be null...

Here is my code:

```
string userControlName = "ReportFilterOptions";                
Type type = this.GetType();
Assembly assembly = type.Assembly;
UserControl c = (UserControl)assembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName + "." + userControlName);
gridReport.Children.Clear();
gridReport.Children.Add(c);
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338016/silverlight-how-to-create-a-page-dynamically/2338131#2338131

Answer (score 2):

Use [System.Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx).

See [this example](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-examples/). The important parts are:

```
// get type of class Calculator from just loaded assembly
Type calcType = testAssembly.GetType("Test.Calculator");

// create instance of class Calculator
object calcInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(calcType);
```

You could make this more "user friendly" by iterating all the types to match string.

See around line 54 of [this file](https://github.com/tedd/Kernel.Module/blob/master/Kernel.Module/Kernel.Module/Module.cs) in method `UpdateClassList`.